# validation style textbox but not on my datepicker wpf

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I have a datepicker that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy',RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also have a textbox on my form.  I want to apply an Validation.ErrorTemplate style on my textbox but not on the textbox that is in my datepicker.  Is there a good way to do this?

I still need validation on my datepicker.

Comment: <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy',RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker}}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah declare style with **`x:Key`** set on it and bind that style only to outer textBox using **`StaticResource`** markup extension so that all textBoxes doesn't inherit that style.

```
<Style x:Key="OuterTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                .....
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and bind to outer textBox like this:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource OuterTextBoxStyle}"/>
```